# How can I handle user input for subprocesses ran in parallel in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, parallel-processing, popen

I have a Python helper function to run grunt commands in parallel, using `Popen` to handle subprocesses. The purpose is communication over CLI. The problem starts when any user input is required for all those processes, e.g. file path, password, 'yes/no' decision:

```
Enter file path: Enter file path: Enter file path: Enter file path: Enter file path: Enter file path: Enter file path: 
Everything up-to-date
Grunt task completed successfully.
```

User provides input once, one process completes successfully and all others never finish executing.

Code:

```
from subprocess import check_output, Popen

def run_grunt_parallel(grunt_commands):

    return_code = 0

    commands = []
    for command in grunt_commands:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as f:
            app = get_grunt_application_name(' '.join(command))
            commands.append({'app': app, 'process': Popen(command, stdout=f)})

    while len(commands):
        sleep(5)
        next_round = []
        for command in commands:
            rc = command['process'].poll()
            if rc == None:
                next_round.append(command)
            else:
                if rc == 0:
                else:
                    return_code = rc

        commands = next_round

    return return_code
```

Is there a way to make sure that user can provide all necessary input for each process?

Comment: Why does the user need to enter file names (as opposed to them being generated by your script)?  Wouldn’t that defeat the purpose of the automation?

Comment: @DavisHerring You're right, it would definitely defeat the purpose. Providing a file name is an example though, this helper is used for communication with various CLIs and I'm not able to predict what information will be requested. It can be either additional data or confirmation.

Comment: You _have_ to know what kind of input the processes expect, so that you can collect it in one location and then pass it to the children.  Otherwise, what’s to stop one process asking for a confirmation that the user thinks came from another?

Comment: @DavisHerring I've clarified the issue description - commands are used by CLIs and for that reason I'm not able to predict what exact input will be expected - will it be response to a 'yes/no' question, prompt to enter passphrase, or something else. I'm looking into using [pexpect](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to listen for specific words in the request. Do you think that's a good idea? Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is *almost* (if not entirely) impossible.  But if you can recognize prompts in a prefix-free fashion (and, if it varies, know from them how many lines of input they expect), you should be able to manage it.

Run each process with two-way unbuffered pipes:

```
Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
      stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
```

(Well-behaved programs prompt on standard error.  Yours seem to do so, since you showed the prompts despite the `stdout=f`; if they don’t do so reliably, you get to read that from a pipe as well, search for prompts in it, and copy it to a file yourself.)

## Unix

Set all pipes non-blocking.  Then use `select` to monitor the `stderr` pipes for all processes.  (You might try `selectors` instead.)  Buffer what you read separately for each process until you recognize a prompt from one.  Then display the prompt (identifying the source process) and accept input from the user—if the output between prompts fits in the pipe buffers, this won’t slow the background work down.  Put that user input in a buffer associated with that process, and add its `stdin` pipe to the `select`.

When a `stdin` pipe shows ready, write to it, and remove it from the set if you finish doing so.  When a read from a pipe returns EOF, `join` the corresponding process (or do so in a `SIGCHLD` handler if you worry that a process might close its end early).

## Windows

Unless you have a `select` emulation available that supports pipes, you’ll have to use threads—one for each process, or one for each pipe if a process might produce output after writing a prompt and before reading the response.  Then use a `Queue` to post prompts as messages to the main thread, which can then use (for example) another per-process `Queue` to send the user input back to the thread (or its writing buddy).

This works on any `threading`-supporting platform and has the potential advantage of not relying on pipe buffers to avoid stalling talkative processes.